# Copy animation incrementaly?

Tags: animation

i have an object at 12 o'clock which rotates around z for 90° to 3 o'clock. Another object located at 3 o'clock should do the same. Rotating around Z for 90° to 6 o'clock...

Is there a way to copy this from first to second object?

My flowchart:

- select object 1
- press "i"
- select "rotation"
- pull "timelinecursor"
- Value Rotation Z "+45°"
- press "i"
- select "rotation"
- pull "timelinecursor" back

Then repeat for the second object

Best regards

Comment: Can't you simply parent the second object to the first ? (Ctrl+P)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you right, you could simply choose "individual origins"

[image]

select all objects, hit I -> rotation, then rotate z 90 degrees and hit i rotation again.

[image]

Comment: Welcome back! ...missed your brain! ;-)

Comment: Thank you mate!!!!

Comment: Oh, thanks... Thats it...

Comment: You are welcome. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you!